# error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'Oper')

Tags: c++, overloading

Task is to load complex number from a file. When code was written without classes, using stuctures and specified functions only it didn't show that error. Functions (>> overlading) were completely the same.

Class

```
#ifndef WYRAZENIE_ZESPOLONE_HH
#define WYRAZENIE_ZESPOLONE_HH

#include "liczbaZespolona.hh"

enum Oper {op_plus, op_minus, op_razy, op_dziel};

class WyrazenieZespolone {
private:
    LiczbaZespolona lz1;
    LiczbaZespolona lz2;
    Oper op;

public:
    
    WyrazenieZespolone() = default;
    WyrazenieZespolone(const LiczbaZespolona, const LiczbaZespolona, Oper);

    LiczbaZespolona oblicz() const;

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const WyrazenieZespolone&);
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream&, WyrazenieZespolone&);
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream&, Oper&);
};

#endif
```

Operators overloading implementation

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& strm, WyrazenieZespolone& wz){
    strm >> wz.lz1 >> wz.op >> wz.lz2;

    return strm;
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& strm, Oper& t_op){
    char znak;

    strm >> znak;
    switch(znak){
        case '+': {t_op = op_plus; break;} 
        case '-': {t_op = op_minus; break;}
        case '*': {t_op = op_razy; break;}
        case '/': {t_op = op_dziel; break;}
        default : {strm.setstate(std::ios::failbit);}
    }
    
    return strm;
}
```

I'm getting such error during compilation, even though vs code doesn't show any mistakes

```
error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'Oper')
     strm >> wz.lz1 >> wz.op >> wz.lz2;
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: what is `LiczbaZespolona` ? and where is its `>>` declared?

Comment: Friending `friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream&, Oper&);` to `WyrazenieZespolone` seems rather pointless, don't you think? Just declare the free function in a header (ideally right the formal declaration of that enum) and make sure you have that decl available before/wherever you use it.

Comment: @WhozCraig but how am I suppose to write to private attributes then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that at the point when you wrote:

```
strm >> wz.lz1 >> wz.op >> wz.lz2;
```

compiler do not have the **definition** of the overloaded `std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& strm, Oper& t_op)` since it is defined afterwards.

So to **solve** this just move the definition of `std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& strm, Oper& t_op)` before the definition of `std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& strm, WyrazenieZespolone& wz)` as shown below. That is for `strm >>wz.op` to work, define the corresponding overloaded `operator>>` before its use.

Similarly, for `strm >> wz.lz1` to work, define the corresponding overloaded `operator>>` before its use. This is shown in the below snippet [Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/0nN4zYQjv).

```
//this comes first so that it can be used in strm >>wz.op
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& strm, Oper& t_op){
    char znak;

    strm >> znak;
    switch(znak){
        case '+': {t_op = op_plus; break;} 
        case '-': {t_op = op_minus; break;}
        case '*': {t_op = op_razy; break;}
        case '/': {t_op = op_dziel; break;}
        default : {strm.setstate(std::ios::failbit);}
    }
    
    return strm;
}
//similarly this comes before so that it can be used in strm >> wz.lz1
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& strm, LiczbaZespolona&)
{
    //do something here 
    return strm;
}
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& strm, WyrazenieZespolone& wz){
    strm >> wz.lz1 >> wz.op >> wz.lz2;

    return strm;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/0nN4zYQjv)